# Hard time setting up a dart project with eclipse plugin

Tags: dart, stagexl

I am setting up a new project (java backend + dart frontend).

On client side I plan to use stagexl as a gaming framework. On server side I will use Google App Engine. (Plus Gradle and GIT ...)

Yesterday I followed http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/01/integrating-dart-into-eclipse-and-your.html for installing the dart eclipse plugin but I get lots of error popups all the time.

*Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed".*

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:134)
    at com.google.dart.tools.ui.DartElementAdapterFactory.getProperties(DartElementAdapterFactory.java:204)
    at com.google.dart.tools.ui.DartElementAdapterFactory.getAdapter(DartElementAdapterFactory.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.adapter.AdapterFactoryProxy.getAdapter(AdapterFactoryProxy.java:80)
    ...
```

My setup:

```
Dart Editor for Eclipse             0.4.5.r21094                 com.google.dart.eclipse.feature.feature.group  dartlang.org
Eclipse EGit                        2.3.1.201302201838-r         org.eclipse.egit.feature.group Eclipse EGit
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  1.5.2.20130211-1820          epp.package.jee    null
Google App Engine Java SDK 1.7.7    1.7.7                        com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.feature.feature.group   Google, Inc.
Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2       3.2.2.v201303261859-rel-r42  com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group Google, Inc.
Gradle IDE  3.2.0.201301240803-M2   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature.feature.group   SpringSource, a division of VMware, Inc.
```

**A beer or two to the one who helps me!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing Eclipse and then installing the Dart plugin, I recommend you to download the Dart Editor from their [page](https://www.dartlang.org/)

That is an already fully functional Eclipse instance prepared for dart usage.

From there, you can create a new project and they will give you some pre-defined templates.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a fully functional Eclipse. Devs who look for integrated CVS, multi-language projects, and others,  DartEditor isn't the right tool.

Comment: That is sad. I haven't tried multi-language projects but I believe you can install CVS plugins.

Comment: No plugin support in DartEditor. They did this to keep it sleek and fast because of many complaints about the slow and heavy Eclipse.